# mysqli aggregate fetched values

Tags: php, reference, mysqli, fetch

I'm trying to write class that encapsulates mysqli logic (strongly using stack **overflow** articles) and I've encounetered this problem: **$row** keys reference to the **recent values** that've been **fetched**, and so does the array **$rows**, in which I want to aggregate fetched values. How those references can be changed to values or (more likely) what is the right approach to do this fetch?

```
private function bind_array(&$row) {
    $md = $this->stmt->result_metadata();
    $params = array();
    while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }

    if(!call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_result'), $params)) {
        throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
    }
}

public function select($query, $data_array, $letters) {

    $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    if(!$this->stmt) {
        throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
    }

    $return_array = array();

    foreach($data_array as $data) {
        array_unshift($data, implode('',$letters));

        $refs = array();

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $refs[$key] = &$data[$key];
        }

        if(!call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_param'), $refs)) {
            throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
        }

        if($this->stmt->execute()) {

            $this->bind_array($row);

            while($this->stmt->fetch()) {

                $rows[] = $row;

            }

            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($rows);
            exit;

        } else {
            throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
        }

        $return_array[] = $rows;

    }


    return $return_array;

}
```

Comment: why you're looping over $data array?

Comment: why you're truing to do two tasks at once? why not to create a method that runs a query and returns statement?

Comment: I prepare statement once and then loop through values

Comment: Yes. And I am curious WHY are you doing that

Comment: I think it is the right way of using prepared statement: not to prepare it multiple times but once. What are your suggestions?

Comment: okay, okay, you are preparing it once. But why you are executing it in a loop?

Comment: okay, suggestions. make your select() function prepare, bind and  execute single query. and then return statement object. without any fetching.